# svg animation not "running" correctly

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

Well, this is my first post, and I usually can solve issues from coming to the community, but now I need some help. I have created a "SVG" that has some animation that over a 24 hour period will transaction through he different cycles of the day. So I been able to use some NPM bundles that do all the calcualtions of the time cycles and calulcate over the time how long each "time period" should last between the SVG gradeints.

The "code" is this:

```
<linearGradient
id="skyGradient"
gradientTransform="rotate(90)"
>
<stop offset="50%">
<animate 
attributeName="stop-color"
begin="39420s"
keyTimes="0;0.19517361111111112;0.21341435185185184;0.23157407407407407;0.2471875;0.2479398148148148;0.4997337962962963;0.7515277777777778;0.7522800925925925;0.7678935185185185;0.7860648148148148;0.8043055555555556;1"
values="black;rgb(0,0,0);rgb(2,15,23);rgb(8,33,48);rgb(46,125,185);rgb(145,193,243);rgb(145,193,243);rgb(46,125,185);rgb(46,125,185);rgb(24,75,106);rgb(10,41,59);rgb(2,15,23);black"
calcMode="linear"
dur="86400s">
</animate>
</stop>
</linearGradient>
```

So this is just one section of the SVG linearGradient and there is three parts, but they all follow the same code.

Code Here: https://jsfiddle.net/2148whup/

So what am I expecting?

I know when a visitor visits, I know the current time in seconds of the current day of their location. So if it's Jun 17, 2023 at 9:30am EDT I know the total seconds from midnight of the day in question which then divided by 86400 will give me the "percentage" of where the animation ***should*** start or the raw seconds and continue until it's finished (if the user stays on the site for the entire rest of the day) which should start based on that the keyTimes it should be between colors at that point. I have reviewed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate in great detail, but am having a hard time getting the animation to even render out even if I force it and even if the code is manually generated does it not work.

I have in my "test" code color codes in RGB or Hex and neither work. Once I get this to work, I can work on javascript which would "update"/regenerate the keyTimes after the 24 hours loop if it does end up going through 24 hours and then restarting all over again.

Comment: Your should first try a time lapsed animation - a duration 365days is pretty hard to test and might not be supported by all browsers. I can see an animation changing duration to e.g 365s. But please add the jsfiddle example to your answer and clarify, what the final result should look like

Comment: 1. Please post your code here (@herrstrietzel by editing the question, not by posting an answer) instead of linking. 2. Fix your typos 3. Think about your use of `repeatCount="indefinite"` ~ why isn't it used in every animation? 4. The [trick](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#OffsetValueSyntax) is to set the `begin` to a negative value, so that the animation _should_ have begun at midnight.

Comment: Ok. Thank you both for your comments.

Comment: Ok. Thank you both for your comments. So... the animation is elapsed over "1 day" or "86400s" and if the animation by default is 1s intervals, it should have no issues. So 0s = midnight, and 86400s is midnight the following day. What I am having an issue is how to set the animation to start lets say at today's "civil dawn" was at Jun 17 2023 05:57:12, which is 21432s from midnight of today. So if I visited the site at 5:57:10 seconds, I want my animation to start from 21430s to go from there. I did fix the color issue and it starting now. New fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2148whup/2/

Comment: I have the "transition" between time frames working and that is reflected in the jsfiddle above. Now the only issue is the "starting" point of the animation. I know one way I can do this is calculate the "starting color". It's a lot of extra code I have to build out, but I do have it in another format. Just wasn't planing on having to do that with the svg, but it still doesn't help as the svg animation would still have to know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

With a slow animation like this and the calculations needed for the animation I think that a better approach would be using JavaScript to update the DOM. Here I "animate" the time of day using the gradientTranform attribute. In this example the gradient is updated every minute.

```js
const gradient = document.getElementById('g1');

function updategradient(){
  let now = new Date();
  let daybegin = new Date();
  daybegin.setMilliseconds(0);
  daybegin.setSeconds(0);
  daybegin.setMinutes(0);
  daybegin.setHours(0);
  let delta = (now - daybegin) / (1000*60*60*24);
  gradient.setAttribute('gradientTransform', `translate(${delta * 100 - 50} 0)`);
  setTimeout(updategradient, 60*1000);
}

updategradient();
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      gradientTransform="translate(-50 0)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="orange" />
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="orange" />
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="green" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="50" fill="url(#g1)"/>
</svg>
```